# Binary number conversion in c language

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Is there any built in function to convert a decimal number to binary number?
Is there any format specifier for binary numbers?
For hex it is %x and for binary?

Comment: You have to do this manually.

Answer (score 2):

No, C does not have binary conversion functions built in. However, they're not hard to write and are a good exercise to demonstrate your understanding of binary arithmetic.

Comment: Well `strtoul( , ,2)` reads binary strings just fine, which is one part of the problem.

Comment: @Cornstalks That would be why the above is a comment to Greg's *"C does not have binary conversion functions built in"* and not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

some libc have it as extension (you can printf a %b ) but here is a basic macro implementation if you just need the string representation of the binary

```
#define putbin(d) do{ \ 
  unsigned long long i=1ULL<<63; \ 
  while (!((unsigned long long) d & (i/=2))); /* optional - remove leading zeroes */ \ 
    do { ( (unsigned long long) d & i) ? write(1,"1",1) : write(1,"0",1); } \
    while (i/=2); \ 
write(1,"\n",1); /* optional - add new line */ \ 
} while (0)
```

Comment: btw, oddly it was dietlibc that had %b option in printf

Comment: This code fails (with an infinite loop) for a pretty common use case.